# Automatic taskbar reveal not working when my WPF app is running from Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, taskbar

When Windows has "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode" = Off, the taskbar is displayed and my app displays in the remaining desktop area, which is correct.

When that setting is set to On, the taskbar is hidden but slides into view when you move the mouse to the edge of the screen. This also works correctly with my app when running the executable in the normal way.

But when my app is launched by Visual Studio 2019 and is maximized and has focus, the taskbar does NOT slide into view when you mouse to the edge.

What's going on here and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure that *"launched by Visual Studio"* shouldn't read *"ran under a debugger"*?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could definitely be caused by any debugger.

Comment: Why are you not sure. It takes like less than a minute to try.

Comment: Because I don't ever use any other debugger. What would you suggest for this?

Comment: Just run the application from Visual Studio without attaching a debugger to it, and see if that makes a difference. Presumably, there's a *"Start Without Debugging"* option available from some menu, though I don't have .NET installed and cannot verify.